# Can you get a word-diff with `git log`?

Tags: git, word-diff

I know that `git diff --word-diff=color` shows a word diff between the working tree and HEAD, but is there a way to get the same kind of output with `git log`?

Comment: what version of git are you using? In version 1.5.5.6, `git diff --color-words rev1..rev2` only gives expected colored output. If I try `git diff --word-diff=color rev1..rev2` it shows the git-diff usage.

Comment: You might have to write up a little script -- Do `git log` in such a way that it just prints the SHA1s, then iterate through those SHA1s and do `git diff --word-diff=color $SHA1^ $SHA1`. Then of course you could assign a git alias to that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about `--color-words`? Additionally you somehow have to activate the diff.

```
git log --color-words -p
```

shows me kind of a colored diff.

Comment: That outputs line diff, not a word diff

Comment: On 1.7.1 and with my settings (nothing diff-related, apart from maybe `color.ui=auto` it outputs a word diff.) Of course only when your source contains word differences (= differences smaller than whole added/removed lines).

Answer (score 1):

OK I think I got it working with

```
git log -m -p --word-diff=plain
```

Comment: This gives me a error: `fatal: unrecognized argument: --word-diff=plain`. What is your git version (`git --version`)?

Comment: git version 1.7.3.2. But on my linux box, which currently has 1.7.0.4, I get the same error.

Comment: So looks like they added the support to `--word-diff` to `git log` between these versions (which makes sense, since the option was already possible for `git diff`).

Comment: Nice.  Now if only git would use that for actual patches, indenting a block of code might not result in merge conflicts!